# Error in R code in a semi supervised algorithm

Tags: r, machine-learning, weka

I'm now trying to write my first code in R for machine learning. I have received an error:

```
could not find function "rpartXse""
```

in spite of installing its package `DMwR` successfully. Also an error message

```
Error in Species ~ Species ~ idx <- sample(150, 100) :    object 'Species' not found
```

although I have installed its package `SPECIES`

Comment: Did you activate the packages after installation? `library(x)` or `require(x)` where `x` is the package name.

Answer (score 0):

Your library name should be `DMwR` and not `DWmR` (just edited the question to correct it) and it should work just fine.

```
library(DMwR)
data(iris)
tree <- rpartXse(Species ~ ., iris)
tree

n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
  2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
  3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
    6) Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259) *
    7) Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
```